# how to require file.node in pkg

Tags: node.js, native-module

I used pkg to ship an executable version of my node app that uses node-native-printer module.

As a prerequisite to run  node-native-printer you need to have edge-js package installed.

To follow form here, using pkg i was able to create the app.exe without any errors or warnings .

The problem tough when I run the app.exe it fails with the below error msg:

> pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1185
>         throw error;
>         ^
>
> Error: Module did not self-register.
>       at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:728:18)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:635:17)
>       at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1166:31)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>       at Object. (C:\snapshot\edge-js-native-printer\node_modules\edge-js\lib\e`enter
>   code here`dge.js:104:8)
>       at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1261:22)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:710:10)

After hours of debugging i found that pkg at run time is unable to require  **edge_nativeclr.node** found at `C:\snapshot\edge-js-native-printer\node_modules\edge-js\lib\native\win32\x64\10.14.0\edge_nativeclr`

here under the code from the edge.js :

```
process.env.EDGE_NATIVE = edgeNative

edge = require(edgeNative) /* pkg fails to require C:\snapshot\edge-js-native-printer\node_modules\edge-js\lib\native\win32\x64\10.14.0\edge_nativeclr */

exports.func = function(language, options) {
  if (!options) {
    options = language
    language = 'cs'
}
```

does anyone come across this issue ? any idea to solve it will be appreciated .

Best regards